# Extracting tweets from specific time, specific users and specifics hashtags

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets

I wrote the code below to get tweets in the specific time, specific users and specifics hashtags,
the code is not working well, the output doesn't show the specific time and hashtag and only users, can anyone please help me?

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sys

# API credentials here
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

# Search word/hashtag value 
HashValue = ""
users = ["BBC",
"SenJohnMcCain",
"JeffFlake",
"SenMarkPryor"]

# search start date value. the search will start from this date to the current date.
StartDate = ""

# getting the search word/hashtag and date range from user
HashValue = input("Enter the hashtag you want the tweets to be downloaded for: ")
StartDate = input("Enter the start date in this format yyyy-mm-dd: ")

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open(HashValue+'.csv', 'a')

#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for user in users:
  for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,
                             screen_name = user,
                             q=HashValue+ "-filter:retweets",
                             count=20,lang="en",
                             since=StartDate,
                             tweet_mode='extended').items(20):
                             
                             
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])

  print ("Scraping finished and saved to "+HashValue+".csv")
```

Also, a small part of the result is shown as below:

````
Enter the hashtag you want the tweets to be downloaded for: #vaccine#iran
Enter the start date in this format yyyy-mm-dd: 2021-01-30
2021-02-01 11:01:07 RT @BBCOne: A brand new thriller from the Executive Producer of Line of Duty and Bodyguard.

Bloodlands. Coming soon to @BBCOne and @BBCiPl…
Scraping finished and saved to #vaccine#iran.csv
2021-01-29 19:00:00 Need help to plan your Lockdown Learning lesson plan for next week? We've got you  @cbbc @bbctwo https
Scraping finished and saved to #vaccine#iran.csv
2021-01-25 15:30:00 Comedian @zoelyons presents the lightning-fast, quick-fire quiz with a £3,000 jackpot ⚡️

#Lightning | Starts tonight at 6:30pm | @BBCTwo 
Scraping finished and saved to #vaccine#iran.csv
2021-01-25 13:47:51 RT @bbcpress:  The quick-fire quiz #Lightning starts today on @BBCTwo at 6.30pm. We caught up with @zoelyons who answered her own lightnin…
Scraping finished and saved to #vaccine#iran.csv
2021-01-22 17:00:01 Joining us for another week of Lockdown Learning? ⁣
⁣```
````

Comment: Can you maybe show us some results at the end of a search?

Comment: I updated the question with the results also

Comment: I mean the output of the `print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)` clearly shows the date and text of the tweet, i.e. `2021-02-01 11:01:07 RT @BBCOne: A brand new thriller from the Executive Producer of Line of Duty and Bodyguard.`. As for the hashtag, you didn't print it try `print(dir(tweet))` to see if there is any `.hashtag` attribute.

Comment: when I run the code, I put hashtags: #vaccine#iran but when I see the text that is extracted, there are no hashtags .. it means it is just random text from the user (in this case BBC), but it didn't consider hashtags..

Comment: Try `q = f"{HashValue} AND -filter:retweets"`

Comment: Thank you, I tried it shows the same results and no hashtags..

Comment: Can you please upload the results?

Comment: the result is the same as I uploaded in the code above

Comment: What happens if you let q be `q = f"{HashValue}"`. Do you get the posts with the right hashtags?

Comment: not, unfortunately .

Comment: Apparently, you can t concatenate two hashtags like that, i.e. `"#something#somethingelse"`. You query parameter would work if you said instead `q="#tsunami OR #summer"` or `q="#tsunami AND #summer"`. Your query space would be bigger when using OR rather than AND.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work like this. if you can run the code.. you will see